# Best Alternative for Converting VB6 to run under Windows 8

Tags: windows, vb6, migration, windows-8

I originally (many years ago) wrote my applications using VB6 on the assumption that it was a strategic Microsoft product and so I would be able to run them as long as I wanted. However with Windows 8 it looks like VB6 will not longer be able to run.

What do people think is a good strategic alternative to VB6 as a simple development environment for applications not needing Internet access (they just run on the PC)? I really do not want to have to convert the applications again in the future.

Comment: @Markust:  I think the OP actually means Windows 8 (or whatever comes after Windows 7).  That's because VB6 core runtime environment will be officially supported by MS for the lifetime of Windows 7 but not beyond.

Comment: There is no evidence that VB6 programs won't run in the next version of Windows, just as there is no evidence that .Net will be supported.  It is simply too early and Microsoft has not released any plans.  We seem to go through this discussion every product cyle now and each time VB6 has been supported.

Comment: +1 Bob. Microsoft say "there are no plans to include VB6 runtime in future versions of Windows beyond Windows 7."

Comment: I won't be surprised if it *isn't* supported.  I just don't see anything today saying that it will not be.  One thing that worries me is Ballmer saying the next version of Windows (he refuses to use the term Windows 8) will be the company's riskiest product ever.  Who knows?  Linux core?  One VM per application running?  Abandonment of .Net?  No WOW64?  Azure everywhere?

Comment: And as we know now, the Win8 Dev Preview at least does include the VB6 runtime libraries.

Comment: Microsoft have now announced the VB6 [runtime is supported on Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/vbrun/ms788708%28en-us%29.aspx). And now... we wait for the statement that "there are no plans to support VB6 in Windows 9".

Answer (score 3):

Go for .net , it runs on a "virtual machine" and it seems it will be here for long time to come. The development cycle is similar to VB6.

Comment: There is even a conversion wizard for VB6, but a scratch rewrite may be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at PowerBasic Compiler for Windows + PowerBasic Forms 2.0...

Answer (score 1):

Delphi is an option and depending on how complex your programs are there are some conversion tools available.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives abound, and choosing a good one is hard enough.  Forget finding a "best" one.

Some people like [Jabaco](http://www.jabaco.org/), which has the advantage of targeting multiple platforms.

Answer (score 0):

VB6 SP6 run perfectly on 8 full version, some kb update will stop system info and rtf tools from loading, so be careful  if in case you app uses them, when doing some kb updates be careful and reimage your system regularly.

WARINING: IF YOU HAVE NOT UPGRADE FROM 8.0 TO 8.1 NOW, PLEASE DON'T, BECAUSE ABOUT 90% OF THE TOOL DOESN'T WORK. IT MAY BE SUPPORTED LATER, SO WAIT.